# readByteSync - is this behavior correct?

Tags: dart

stdin.readByteSync has recently been added to Dart.

Using stdin.readByteSync for data entry, I am attempting to allow a default value and if an entry is made by the operator, to clear the default value. If no entry is made and just enter is pressed, then the default is used.

What appears to be happening however is that no terminal output is sent to the terminal until a newline character is entered. Therefore when I do a print() or a stdout.write(), it is delayed until newline is entered.

Therefore, when operator enters first character to override default, the default is not cleared. IE. The default is "abc", data entered is "xx", however "xxc" is showing on screen after entry of "xx". The "problem" appears to be that no "writes" to the terminal are sent until newline is entered.

While I can find an alternative way of doing this, I would like to know if this is the way readByteSync should or must work. If so, I’ll find an alternative way of doing what I want.

// Example program //

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main () {
  int iInput;
  List<int> lCharCodes = [];
  print(""); print("");
  String sDefault = "abc";
  stdout.write ("Enter data : $sDefault\b\b\b");
  while (iInput != 10) {   // wait for newline
    iInput = stdin.readByteSync();
    if (iInput == 8 && lCharCodes.length > 0) { // bs
      lCharCodes.removeLast();
    } else if (iInput > 31) {   // ascii printable char
      lCharCodes.add(iInput);
      if (lCharCodes.length == 1)
        stdout.write ("    \b\b\b\b chars cleared");  // clear line
      print ("\nlCharCodes length = ${lCharCodes.length}");
    }
  }
  print ("\nData entered = ${new String.fromCharCodes(lCharCodes).trim()}");
}
```

Results on Command screen are :

```
c:\Users\Brian\dart-dev1\test\bin>dart testsync001.dart


Enter data : xxc
 chars cleared
lCharCodes length = 1

lCharCodes length = 2

Data entered = xx

c:\Users\Brian\dart-dev1\test\bin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently added stdin.readByteSync and readLineSync, to easier create small scrips reading the stdin. However, two things are still missing, for this to be feature-complete.

1) Line mode vs Raw mode. This is basically what you are asking for, a way to get a char as soon as it's printed.

2) Echo on/off. This mode is useful for e.g. typing in passwords, so you can disable the default echo of the characters.

I hope to be able to implement and land these features rather soon.

You can star [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9825) to track the development of it!

Comment: Thanks, I've voted for that. However, shouldn't readByteSync() "logically" return bytes as they are entered? As far as I can determine, one may as well use readLineSync(), because it appears (to me) that nothing is returned until newline is entered.

Comment: While it would make sense for `readByteSync()` to return immediately, it's not the default behavior on any platform. That's why I want to provide it as an option/mode.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info, and thanks for adding the console Sync functions, they help a lot. I initially wanted readLineSync(), so I got that which is great. Because readByteSync() was there, I thought I would use it, hence my post here.

Comment: I think you better mention in your profile that you work for Google and one of the programmers developing the Dart. :)

Comment: Shadow - I wish :) My hat is off to those guys. I'm still very much the student :).

Comment: Shadow - Sorry, I guess you mean Anders :) .

Answer (score 0):

This is common behavior for consoles. Try to flush the output with `stdout.flush()`.

Edit: my mistake. I looked at a very old revision ([dartlang-test](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/tests/standalone/io/file_output_stream_test.dart?spec=svn10455&r=10455)). The current API does not provide any means to flush stdout. Feel free to file a bug.

Comment: I did previously look for a flush() method, but there doesn't appear to be one.

Comment: I also downloaded latest Editor etc. (25017), but results did not change to previous. It appears to me, from running in debugger, that readByteSync() appears to currently use readLineSync() and then return bytes one-by-one. If that is so, nothing can be done in program until all bytes have been entered. Also, if that is so, it could pose problems for more complex uses than this example.

Comment: You are right. I looked at an old revision. Edited the answer.